# Apple Script folder action not working: Need to change file extension

Tags: macos, applescript, action, directory

I'm kind of a beginner at this, so hopefully this is a simple problem:

I'm trying to create a folder action that will change a file with extension ".jpeg" to ".jpg" when it's put in a given folder.

I set up a folder action to do this, but it's not doing anything for some reason.

here's my script:

```
on adding folder items to this_folder after receiving added_items
    display dialog "hello" as text --> Does not display anything
    repeat with theItem in the added_items
        tell application "Finder"
            set n to name extension of theItem
            if n = "jpeg" then
                set name extension of theItem to "jpg"
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

Any guesses?

Comment: It looks like you have set up the folder action incorrectly. I can't see a reason why the dialog wouldn't display, which means that the script is probably never triggered.

Answer (score 2):

#### Check that folder actions are globally enabled:

Run application `Folder Actions Setup` (`/System/Library/CoreServices/Folder Actions Setup.app`) and ensure that `Enable Folder Actions` is checked.

#### Check to make sure that your specific script is installed as a folder action:

In the same application:

- Does the target folder show up in the list on the left?
- If it does and you select it, is your script listed in the list on the right?

Note that folder-action scripts must be saved in one of 2 locations:

- `/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts`  (machine-wide)
- `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts` (user-specific)

---

Also note that you can alternatively use `Automator` to create folder actions, but only for files being *added* (not removed) - this would allow you to use a language other than AppleScript, if desired.

Note, however, that neither mechanism allows you to react to files getting *modified*.

Incidentally, your debug alert could be written more simply as:

```
display alert "hello"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm really not sure why this made a difference, but I changed the debug message to match your suggestion and the script started working!

Comment: @bumsted: Curious - while your original `display` statement is a little awkward, I would still expect it to work. I'm glad your problem  is solved, though. If you feel that my answer helped you, please click the transparent checkmark next to it in order to mark it as accepted.